# How to convert df with multiple observations per id to single observation with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have multiple (in my case exactly 2, but this may vary) observations per 'group' and want to convert this info to a single observation as shown below.
Maybe I miss something obvious here but how to convert

```
    type    value
group       
A   1   0.3
A   2   0.1
B   3   0.2
B   1   0.1
```

into

```
    type1   value1  type2   value2
group               
A   1   0.3 2   0.1
B   3   0.2 1   0.1
```

Comment: Some search terms to help you: your data is in "long format" and you are looking to put it into "wide format". This operation is variously known as "pivoting", "reshaping", "casting", or "unstacking".

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new index level and unstack:

```
new_df = (df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()+1, append=True)
   .unstack(level=-1)
   .sort_index(level=(1,0), axis=1)
)

new_df.columns = [f'{x[0]}{x[1]}' for x in new_df.columns]
```

Output:

```
       type1  value1  type2  value2
group                              
A          1     0.3      2     0.1
B          3     0.2      1     0.1
```